# Using Android navigation component with single activiy, layout drawer and toolbars inside fragments

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigationview

Is it possible to use Android Navigation component/graph in the single activity app in which each fragment has its own toolbar?

Also, container activity has a navigation drawer that needs setup with toolbar and navigation controller, but at the time of activity creation I don't have yet the toolbar.

I am using this code (called in onCreate)

```
    private fun setupNavigation() {

//        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    val drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout);

    val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.drawer_navigation_view);

    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigation_host_fragment);

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}
```

But since I don't have toolbar at the time it throws an error (ActionBar.setTitle called on a null object).

Is it possible to have this, or I need to drop the idea to use navigation component in this case?

Comment: Here is a simple approach using an interface https://stackoverflow.com/a/72882333/9998809

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only requirement is that you call `setupActionBarWithNavController` after you call `setSupportActionBar()`. If you're doing that in your Fragment, then just call `setupActionBarWithNavController` directly after that.

For example, in your Fragment:

```
private fun onViewCreated(view: View, bundle: savedInstanceState) {

  val toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar);
  // Set the Toolbar as your activity's ActionBar
  requireActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  // Find the activity's DrawerLayout
  val drawerLayout = requireActivity().findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout);

  // Find this Fragment's NavController
  val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);

  // And set up the ActionBar
  NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
}
```

There's also a separate `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` method that takes a `Toolbar`. This would be appropriate if you aren't actually using any of the other ActionBar APIs.

Comment: It's maybe a stupid question, but would this reset the navigation backstack? 
For example, if I click on the back while in  that fragment, will it know where to return?

Comment: It is the same NavController instance, so yes it would know where to go.

Comment: A little late but I've found that calling the setSupportActionBar method in the onViewCreated method of a fragment as shown above, often causes the title of the action bar to be changed prior to the transaction animation from the previous fragment which obviously isn't particularly desirable. After a fair bit of searching I haven't been able to find much information on how to set different toolbars across multiple fragments linked by a navigation fragment in a single activity. Is this a known issue with the approach provided in the solution?

Comment: @JoshHardman - sounds like you're running into [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118790652), which suggests not using `android:label` at all, but using a fixed title in your Toolbar (since you never want it to change from its fixed value anyways when using the Toolbar within a Fragment's layout anyways).

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply Ian, I've been watching a few of your talks to try and get my head around this one! I did play around with removing the label attributes earlier which didn't quite seem to work out but I'll have another crack at it

Comment: That appears to have resolved the issue of changing text, but a similar issue persists with changes to the actionbar's home button across fragments. (Specifically when transitioning from a fragment with one to a top level destination without or vice versa)

Comment: @ianhanniballake I made it [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788452/animation-issues-when-using-bottomnavigationview-with-navcontroller-and-each-fra)

Comment: @ianhanniballake What happens if one of the fragments, by design, doesn't have a toolbar in it? There is no `toolbar` view to call `setupActionBarWithNavController` with it. Is it necessary to remove toolbar of previous fragment? I guess calling `setSupportActionBar(null)` in `onDestroyView` will result in nullpointerexception from navigation component.

Comment: @ianhanniballake It turns out not setting new toolbar as supportActionBar in next fragment will leak the toolbar view of previous fragment. So, something has to be done with it. But it looks incorrect to put 0 height toolbar in all fragments, which don't have toolbar in their design, just for the sake of setting it as supportActionBar.

Comment: Using this approach, each toolbar flashes every time you switch between fragments. Has someone experienced this?