# Animation issues when using BottomNavigationView with NavController and each Fragment has its own Toolbar

Tags: android-actionbar, android-animation, android-toolbar, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm developing an app in Kotlin using some of the latest Android Jetepack components. I've recently had a bit of a hitch with the following case:

This issue seems to occur when using `BottomNavigationView` with `NavController`, and when each `Fragment` has its own `Toolbar`. The problem is that when transitioning from Fragment A to Fragment B, changes to **titles** and **ActionBar navigation icons** are updated in Fragment A **and** B. Ideally, for a smooth transition there would be no change to the state of the AppBar in Fragment A. I have a suspicion this might stem from the fact that these properties don't "belong to" the `Toolbar` as this doesn't seem to affect the Toolbar's menu items in the same way.

A work-around for the AppBar titles is setting the title property of each Toolbar in its respective fragment_layout.xml, while also removing the label property from the navFragment.xml (which is usually responsible for setting the title text of the AppBar when using the navController).

**However**, this doesn't solve the issue of actionBar navigation icons like the Up / Home button which don't appear on top-level destinations but do on others. And so in my case it still appears pretty janky.

I've wired up the nav as follows:

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding: MainActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_fragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.fragment_1_main, R.id.fragment_2_main))
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

ExampleFragment.kt

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, (requireActivity() as MainActivity).navController, (requireActivity() as MainActivity).appBarConfiguration)

    }
```

Halp!

Comment: I've also reported this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144444383) on the Google issue tracker. Here you can see how I've set up my xml files for the activity and fragments including the nav fragment.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: No. I ended up taking another approach