# Navigation Component: How to set drawer with toolbar in each fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using navigation component and want to connect drawer layout with toolbar in each fragment, not the activity.

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57547501/13434343) which is called on onViewCreated() but any view referenced from the activity is null. I guess it's because fragment is inflated in the layout before returning from the activity's onCreate method.

I use this extension function to connect the drawer with the fragment's toolbar, I tried to call it from onCreateView() and onViewCreated() but did't work and the activity's drawer layout is always null. I works only if it's called from onStart() but I don't think it's the right way:

```
private fun AppCompatActivity.setToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
    binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController(), drawer)
}
```

What's the right place to call this function?

Comment: Are you using the `<fragment>` tag? That answer works perfectly when using `FragmentContainerView`, which is the recommended way of adding your `NavHostFragment`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake It turns out this's the problem. I used to prefer `fragment` over `FragmentContainerView` because it shows the preview. Can you explain why `fragment` doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `setContentView(R.id.activity_layout)`, the entire view hierarchy is first inflated, then attached to the Activity. It is only after `setContentView()` returns that `findViewById()` will find any of the newly inflated views.

When you use the `<fragment>` tag, the Fragment's view and the views of all of its child fragments are synchronously created as part of that inflation call. This means that `setContentView()` has not completed by the time the `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()` methods are called. This is why that calling `findViewById()` returns null - the activity's view hasn't actually finished being created.

`FragmentContainerView` was specifically built to avoid these special cases and instead use the same mechanisms as other fragments - namely, it just uses a normal `FragmentTransaction` to add your Fragment - the same as if you called `beginTransaction()`+`commitNow()` in your `onCreate()` method yourself. This means that the Fragment is not forced to synchronously create its view as part of `setContentView()`, but can do it alongside every other Fragment **after** `setContentView()` returns. This is what allows `findViewById()` from `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()` work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply using an interface which you need to implement in activity. No need to reference activity's drawerLayout from fragment.

Interface like this:

```
interface DrawerWithToolbar {
    fun setupToolbarDrawer(toolbar: MaterialToolbar)
}
```

Then in activity:

```
override fun setupToolbarDrawer(toolbar: MaterialToolbar) {
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,drawerLayout)
    }
```

In fragment:

```
(activity as DrawerWithToolbar).setupToolbarDrawer(toolbar)
```